# Data type of an intermediate variable

Tags: c++

I am writing a program (in cpp) to check the primality of a given number

The point where i am struck is , I need to check in between the program wether the value i obtained upon some arithmetic operations on the input is an integer or not

i.e lets say input is 'a'

I want to know how to check if 'b' is integer or not (FYI, b=(a+1)/6 )

My attempt for this :

```
int main()
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    int b,c;
    int a;
    cout<<"enter the number";
    cin>>a;
    b=(a+1)/6;
    c=(a-1)/6;
    if (b is an integer)
        cout << "The given number is  prime";
    else if (c is an integer)
        cin << "The given number is  prime!";
    else
        cout<<"The number is not prime";                  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you declare the variables as integers, the result will always integer numbers.

Comment: I think what you want to test is whether `b * 6 == a + 1` and whether `c * 6 == a - 1`. They're integers because you've defined them as integers. What you want to find out is whether any fractional part was lost in the division. One easy way to test that is to multiply and compare. (By the way, this is a *very* odd definition of 'prime'. I've never heard of 35 being prime or 49 being prime! before.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thx man, you are right, i read the definition that all primes are of form 6n+1 or 6n-1 but the thing is all numbers of such form arent primes, anyways learnt a way to do such types if i encounter in future, thx for pointing that out to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `if (((a+1)%6) == 0)` (see the [modulus operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)).

Answer (score 1):

As `a` and `1` both have type `int`, so does `a+1` and `(a+1)`. As `6` also has type `int`, `(a+1)/6` will also have type `int` whatever the value of `a`.

What I think you really want to know is whether `6` evenly divides `(a+1)`. For this you can use the modulus operator. `6` evenly divides `(a+1)` if and only if `(a+1)%6 == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the modulus operator `%` as suggested in other answers is probably the best solution, but to answer your question more literally, you can tell whether the result of an integer division is exact like this:

```
b=(a+1)/6;
c=(a-1)/6;
if (b * 6 == a + 1) // if b is an integer
    cout << "The given number is  prime";
else if (c * 6 == a - 1) // if c is an integer
    cin << "The given number is  prime!";
else
    cout<<"The number is not prime";
```